# SE robots don't index pages from sitemap.xml

Tags: indexing, google-analytics, sitemap, robots.txt, google-search-console

I uploaded a sitemap to my site and not all the url's have been indexed. I've got a bunch of url's which have not been indexed by Google. And I don't know why happen this ...

Right now, I've got 716 url's withount indexing.

[image]

If I watch which url's have not been indexed we've got this example of url's:

[image]

All these url's are completely accesible. If you make click in some of them, you can access to the site correctly:

```
https://www.calzadosniza.es/es/mujer/zapatos-mujer/zapato-descubierto-puntera-charol-ancho-juan-mastre-108-7920#/62-tallas_grandes-40/116-color-azul
https://www.calzadosniza.es/es/mujer/sandalias-mujer/sandalia-cuna-pala-cruzada-combi-plata-glenda-porronet-6551-porronet-8751#/62-tallas_grandes-40/114-color-blanco
https://www.calzadosniza.es/es/mujer/botas-y-botines-mujer/bota-militar-cordon-piso-volumen-2670-tekila-3999#/63-tallas_grandes-41/113-color-negro
```

If I inspect one of them, for example this: https://www.calzadosniza.es/es/mujer/zapatos-mujer/zapato-descubierto-puntera-charol-ancho-juan-mastre-108-7920#/62-tallas_grandes-40/116-color-azul

I've got this result:

[image]

My robot.txt file is:

```
# Allow Directives
Allow: */modules/*.css
Allow: */modules/*.js
Allow: */modules/*.png
Allow: */modules/*.jpg
# Private pages
Disallow: /*?orderby=
Disallow: /*?orderway=
Disallow: /*?tag=
Disallow: /*?id_currency=
Disallow: /*?search_query=
Disallow: /*?back=
Disallow: /*?n=
Disallow: /*&orderby=
Disallow: /*&orderway=
Disallow: /*&tag=
Disallow: /*&id_currency=
Disallow: /*&search_query=
Disallow: /*&back=
Disallow: /*&n=
Disallow: /*controller=addresses
Disallow: /*controller=address
Disallow: /*controller=authentication
Disallow: /*controller=cart
Disallow: /*controller=discount
Disallow: /*controller=footer
Disallow: /*controller=get-file
Disallow: /*controller=header
Disallow: /*controller=history
Disallow: /*controller=identity
Disallow: /*controller=images.inc
Disallow: /*controller=init
Disallow: /*controller=my-account
Disallow: /*controller=order
Disallow: /*controller=order-slip
Disallow: /*controller=order-detail
Disallow: /*controller=order-follow
Disallow: /*controller=order-return
Disallow: /*controller=order-confirmation
Disallow: /*controller=pagination
Disallow: /*controller=password
Disallow: /*controller=pdf-invoice
Disallow: /*controller=pdf-order-return
Disallow: /*controller=pdf-order-slip
Disallow: /*controller=product-sort
Disallow: /*controller=search
Disallow: /*controller=statistics
Disallow: /*controller=attachment
Disallow: /*controller=guest-tracking
# Directories
Disallow: */cache/
Disallow: */classes/
Disallow: */config/
Disallow: */controllers/
Disallow: */css/
Disallow: */download/
Disallow: */js/
Disallow: */localization/
Disallow: */log/
Disallow: */mails/
Disallow: */modules/
Disallow: */override/
Disallow: */pdf/
Disallow: */src/
Disallow: */tools/
Disallow: */translations/
Disallow: */upload/
Disallow: */vendor/
Disallow: */web/
Disallow: */webservice/
# Files
Disallow: /*es/password-recovery
Disallow: /*es/address
Disallow: /*es/addresses
Disallow: /*es/login
Disallow: /*es/cart
Disallow: /*es/discount
Disallow: /*es/order-history
Disallow: /*es/identity
Disallow: /*es/my-account
Disallow: /*es/order-follow
Disallow: /*es/credit-slip
Disallow: /*es/order
Disallow: /*es/search
Disallow: /*es/guest-tracking
Disallow: /*es/order-confirmation
Disallow: /*ca/password-recovery
Disallow: /*ca/address
Disallow: /*ca/addresses
Disallow: /*ca/login
Disallow: /*ca/cart
Disallow: /*ca/discount
Disallow: /*ca/order-history
Disallow: /*ca/identity
Disallow: /*ca/my-account
Disallow: /*ca/order-follow
Disallow: /*ca/credit-slip
Disallow: /*ca/order
Disallow: /*ca/search
Disallow: /*ca/guest-tracking
Disallow: /*ca/order-confirmation
Disallow: /*gl/password-recovery
Disallow: /*gl/address
Disallow: /*gl/addresses
Disallow: /*gl/login
Disallow: /*gl/cart
Disallow: /*gl/discount
Disallow: /*gl/order-history
Disallow: /*gl/identity
Disallow: /*gl/my-account
Disallow: /*gl/order-follow
Disallow: /*gl/credit-slip
Disallow: /*gl/order
Disallow: /*gl/search
Disallow: /*gl/guest-tracking
Disallow: /*gl/order-confirmation
Disallow: /*eu/password-recovery
Disallow: /*eu/address
Disallow: /*eu/addresses
Disallow: /*eu/login
Disallow: /*eu/cart
Disallow: /*eu/discount
Disallow: /*eu/order-history
Disallow: /*eu/identity
Disallow: /*eu/my-account
Disallow: /*eu/order-follow
Disallow: /*eu/credit-slip
Disallow: /*eu/order
Disallow: /*eu/search
Disallow: /*eu/guest-tracking
Disallow: /*eu/order-confirmation
```

So, Why all these url's are not been indexed when I upload my sitemap to Google Console Search?

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitemap is not directive for Search Engines, it's just recommendation. SE can't crawl all pages, use "Priority" field in your sitemap.

Try to check html on unindexed pages manually, may be there is prohibition tag:

`<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />`

Comment: Hi @zborovskaya!!! Thanks for your appreciated help!!! I have checked the source code of one page and there is no any tag meta for robots. Do you know how to set the priority to a sitemap automatically? Right now, my sitemap has 1055 url's ... Do you know some free service? Or pay service which make a sitemap with priority?

Comment: @JoséCarlos Unfortunately I don't know actual tools for sitemaps, I have been working in SEO few years ago.